# Release date for Ubuntu for Android

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Release date for Ubuntu for Android other than the Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 phone architecture???

Any one have an offical response for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official wiki, with the compatible devices, the working devices and the work in progress : [wiki ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)

I think this is the most (if not the only) reliable source for ubuntu touch compatibility.

Comment: That refers to Ubuntu Touch, not Ubuntu for Android.

Comment: You're right, my bad !

Answer (score 1):

There is no official release date for Ubuntu for Andriod, and there might never be one. This depends on hardware makers taking it up and shipping devices with it.

[LinuxonAndroid](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/linuxonandroid) is an alternative independent of OEMs worth to check out.